# How to mock the server side API response in Next JS for playwright

Tags: next.js, playwright

Hi I am trying to mock an API which is present in the server side of a node JS application. But I am not able to do it.

I guess this code only mocks the API being called in the client side:

```
await page.route('https://customisation/steps', route => {
            route.fulfill({
                status: 200,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: JSON.stringify({ data: 'mocked response' }),
            });
        });
```

Can someone help me with the server side mock?

Comment: You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server it's a very simple lib working as fake api.

Comment: In theory, using mock-service-worker could help with this, but it doesn't work right now due to next.js patching fetch (msw also does this and so they interfere). I hope/expect using msw for mocking API's in playwright tests will be a viable solution. https://github.com/mswjs/msw/issues/1644 is the issue to follow for this.